# Application_BeginRequest called for images

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, httphandler

I've seen a few posts about `Application_BeginRequest`, but non seems to have my problem.

My `Application_BeginRequest` is being called for every image in my website.

The `StaticFileHandler` is enabled with * as the Path, but it's at the end of the list.

Is this the normal behaviour? Or should I add `.gif`, `.jpg` and so on on top of the list?

This is on my IIS7.5 Win7 Development Server. Didn't check it on the production server yet.

**Update:**
Setting `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"` would help. But then the ASP.NET URL Mapping does not work anymore. I tried disable it just for the image directly, but that had no effect?

```
<location path="Resources">
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
<location>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure this value is false in your web.config.

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
```

if you are running an MVC app I'd suggest looking at this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tmarq/how-asp-net-mvc-routing-works-and-its-impact-on-the-performance-of-static-requests)

Comment: I guess that would  help, but then my URL Mapping Code will not work anymore. At least that is what happend.
I tried to do that for the images directory, like in the updated Question, but that didn't work either unfortunatly.

Comment: @Remy What "URL Mapping Code" are you talking about? MVC routing, a url rewrite module, or something else? If it is the former, check out [this link](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html).